# Correct cumulative distribution function notation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, notation

If I have a random variable, $v_{A}$, distributed by CDF $G$ on $[v_1,v_2]$, then is it correct to refer to the CDF as $G(v_{A}),$ or should I instead use a generic $v$, and so $G(v)?$ Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Random variables are actually functions (yes, really confusing!).

A more precise notation would be something like this:

$$G_{\nu_A}(x), \;x \in [\nu_1,\nu_2]$$

This emphasizes that G is an ordinary function.